# С# SQL запрос курсовик

Tags: c#, sql

Выполняю курсовую работу (вот так программа для инженера АСУТП):

> 1. По описанию предметной области разработать реляционную базу данных  сети магазинов. База данных должна содержать сведения о следующих
>    объектах: • Магазины – название, адрес, персонал; • Продавцы –
>    фамилия, должность; • Выручка – дата, магазин, товар, продавец, сумма
>    продажи. Базу данных можно создать любыми средствами, например,
>    Database Desktop, Microsoft Access, Microsoft SQL Server и др.
> 2. С помощью любого языка программирования создать формы для  заполнения таблиц разработанной базы данных и внести в таблицы 5-10
>    записей.
> 3. Используя полученную базу данных, создать отчет, формирующий  список продавцов, чью выручка за определенный период больше заданной;
>    список  продавцов вывести сгруппированным по магазинам

Первые 2 пункта были выполнены (не знаю как, но работает), делал согласно найденному [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBUFcMNvEUo), но как сделать 3 пункт вообще ничего похожего не нашёл.

Т.к. особо требований к формату отчёта нет решил сделать вывод через **DataGridView**, метод и запрос изложен ниже:

```
private void RefreshDataGridOt(DataGridView dgw4)     {
            dgw4.Rows.Clear();

            string queryString = $"SELECT SUM(Gain) FROM [Store].[dbo].[Revenue] WHERE NameStaff = N'Иванов'";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, dB.GetConnection());

            dB.OpenConnectionDB();

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ReadSingleRowOt(dgw4, reader);
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
```

Запрос что у меня получился выводит сумму выручки из всей таблицы, когда мне нужно значения фамилий с суммой не меньшей введённой, и ещё как то по дате это отсортировать. Такое чувство, что нужна какая то промежуточная таблица, но как это реализовать? Куда копать?

Вывод в программе:
[image: Программа]

**Спасибо всем за помощь, разобрался, всё работает как нужно :)
Код, может кому пригодится:**

```
private void RefreshDataGridOt(DataGridView dgw4) //выводим данные из БД таблица отчёт
        {
            dgw4.Rows.Clear();

            var sum_gain = textBox_ot_sum.Text;
            var before_date = dateTimePicker_ot.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            var after_date = dateTimePicker_do.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");


            string queryString = $"SELECT NameStaff, SUM(Gain) FROM [Store].[dbo].[Revenue] WHERE Gain > {sum_gain} AND Date BETWEEN '{before_date}' AND '{after_date}'  GROUP BY NameStaff";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, dB.GetConnection());

            dB.OpenConnectionDB();

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ReadSingleRowOt(dgw4, reader);
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Вы почитайте хоть что-нибудь по SQL... что такое группировка и зачем - в частности.

Comment: таки да, SQL запрос не верен относительно вашей логики, если я правильно ее понял

Comment: Как инженер АСУТП с тридцатилетним стажем скажу, что задача -  самое то. Для любого инженера. Современный инженер должен уметь обрабатывать информацию с помощью вычислительных средств.

Comment: @rotabor Спасибо за помощь! От себя добавлю, разработчику ПО для контроллерного оборудования этого материала очень недостаточно, а мне, как эксплуатации это избыточно, заморочился с работой только потому что мне это интересно и хотелось разобраться.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо за наводку, преподаватель уволился, спросить было не у кого)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хорошо поставленная задача - половина решения: "список продавцов, чью выручка за определенный период больше заданной; список продавцов вывести сгруппированным по магазинам" = "SELECT продавцов WHERE выручка > заданной AND дата BETWEEN начало периода AND конец периода GROUP BY магазинам"

Comment: Для начала советую настроить SQL запрос в том же Access (а там его можно создать графически и получить текст на SQL) или SQL Server Management Studio, а потом уже вставить его в программу.